# Rolify has_role? method returning false instead of true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I have added Rolify gem to my project and successfully initialised it. I am facing a strange problem?

The user object has user and admin roles.

```
[1] pry(#<API::V1::PostPolicy>)> current_user.roles
=> [#<API::V1::Role:0x007fb70602be48
  id: "19810121-ea16-4d86-b36c-475fad0f7dec",
  name: "user",
  resource_id: nil,
  resource_type: nil,
  created_at: Thu, 02 Apr 2015 02:05:27 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 02 Apr 2015 02:05:27 UTC +00:00>,
 #<API::V1::Role:0x007fb705ee6858
  id: "a51c59e2-9dd0-4838-b159-1af11f7db15d",
  name: "admin",
  resource_id: nil,
  resource_type: nil,
  created_at: Thu, 02 Apr 2015 02:05:27 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 02 Apr 2015 02:05:27 UTC +00:00>]
```

When I query for admin roles, I see a strange behavior.

```
[2] pry(#<API::V1::PostPolicy>)> current_user.has_role? :admin
=> false
```

I am trying to enforce policies using Pundit and Rolify and the above output is from Policy test.

V

**Update**

I am using UUID with rolify. The migration for rolify is as follows.

```
   class RolifyCreateAPIV1Roles < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :api_v1_roles, id: :uuid do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.uuid :resource_id
          t.string :resource_type

          t.timestamps
       end

    create_table(:api_v1_users_api_v1_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.uuid :user_id
      t.uuid :role_id
    end

    add_index(:api_v1_roles, :name)
    add_index(:api_v1_roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:api_v1_users_api_v1_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `user.add_role :admin` or `user.add_role :admin, Post`
and then  `user.has_role? :admin`
If it still fails then I believe indexing between the user and role record was not set.

Comment: I see. try `user.reload`

Comment: I did tried all the methods suggested. As you suspect, this could be something to do with indexing. I have updated my post with migration file for rolify tables.

Comment: On the table, `api_v1_users_api_v1_roles`, why is the id `false`? change it to true and drop&create tables and migrate in sqlite

Comment: I found out the issue. It was my mistake. I forgot to change the primary key of user table to UUID. Thanks for leading me to the problem. V

Comment: Haha. Awesome! Yeah it happens when juggling some tables and columns ;)